# best book for real analysis for undergraduate

Tags: soft-question, advice

I am in under graduate first year. I want to learn some advanced real analysis. Can you give me some suggestions? One suggestion I got is Rudin's mathematical analysis. Can I buy that?

Comment: Rudin or "baby" Rudin?

Comment: Gilbert Strang - Calculus

Comment: I think walter rudin

Comment: @SankarSam Rudin has two main books used in teaching/learning analysis. The easier to work with one is often called Baby Rudin. It doesn't leave as much to the reader as "adult" Rudin does. I asked my question because if "adult" Rudin is the only suggestion given so far, I'd suggest Baby Rudin or something else.

Answer (score 2):

If you want single variable stuff, Abbott's *Understanding Analysis* is a good start. It is sort of like a baby Baby Rudin.

If you want both single and multivariable analysis, my personal favorite is Fitzpatrick's *Advanced Calculus*.

The texts by Rudin are also of course "the standard" in analysis.

If you want to look at complex analysis, I like a book by Saff and Snider called *Fundamentals of Complex Analysis for Mathematics, Science, and Engineering*.